# Preventing component redraw Mithril + ChartJS

Tags: view, components, chart.js, redraw, mithril.js

I'm trying to draw in a canvas created in a Mithril's component. My problem is that I don't want this component's view to be redrawn when the application needs. I found that the onremove/oncreate methods are calling each time a redraw is launched. Does Mithril recreate my canvas each time the application is redrawn ? Is there a solution to avoid that because I can't call createPlot() each time the application need a redraw... ?

My code :

```
export default function ResultsLinePlot(state){
    return {
        onremove: function() {

        },
        oncreate: function(){
            if(_filter(state)){
                createPlot() // ChartJS draw the plot in the canvas "ChartLinePlot"
            }
        },
        view : function(){
            return _filter(state) ? m('div', {class: 'row'}, [
                (state.results.length > 0) ? m('div', {class: 'col-md-12'},[
                    m('canvas',{id:"chartLinePlot",width:"400",height:"400"})
                ]) : null
            ]) : null
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try changing to `oninit` instead and maybe use a stream to update the view when needed

Comment: Looks very much like a confusion between oninit and oncreate.